# What terminating condition for this recursive flood fill implementation?

Tags: c, recursion, sdl, flood-fill

I have a recursive flood fill algorithm set up that keeps segfaulting due to (I think) stack overflow/recursion depth reached. I don't want to mess with the stack limits and creating an iterative version of this particular algorithm is beyond my skill level. So, I just want the function to stop after so many loops, so it will only fill safely small areas.

I've created a test program to play around with the implementation of a terminating condition however I've noticed that the function keeps running despite finishing it's job. For example, in the code below, letting it run for 200,000 times fills the window correctly, but so does 300,000 and when I let it run for 400,000 times, it safely stops the loop at 337,977. So I'm confused as to what exactly is stopping it at 337,977 and how I can get it to stop at the actual end of the flood fill that I can see with my eyes takes less than 200,000 loops.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
Uint32 myPixelColour(Uint32 *pixels, int x, int y, int windowWidth, int windowHeight)
{

    Uint32 thisPixelColour = 0;
    thisPixelColour = pixels[x + y * windowWidth];
    return thisPixelColour;
}

int mySameColour(Uint32 thisPixelColour, Uint32 thatPixelColour)
{
    return (thisPixelColour == thatPixelColour);
}

void myFill(Uint32 *pixels, int windowWidth, int windowHeight, int x, int y, Uint32 finColour, int *counter)
{
    if(!((x>=0) && (x<windowWidth) && (y>=0) && (y<windowHeight))) return;
    if(*counter == 400000) return;  /* 200000 fills the window, so does 300000 */
    printf("%d\n", *counter);
    *counter = *counter + 1;

    Uint32 ogColour = myPixelColour(pixels, x, y, windowWidth, windowHeight);
    if(mySameColour(ogColour, finColour)) return;
    pixels[x+y*windowWidth] = finColour;

    myFill(pixels, windowWidth, windowHeight, x, y+1, finColour, counter);
    myFill(pixels, windowWidth, windowHeight, x-1, y, finColour, counter);
    myFill(pixels, windowWidth, windowHeight, x, y-1, finColour, counter);
    myFill(pixels, windowWidth, windowHeight, x+1, y, finColour, counter);
}

int main(void)
{
    const int windowWidth = 400;
    const int windowHeight = 212;
    int counter;
    counter = 1;

    SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow("WindowTitle", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, windowWidth, windowHeight, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    SDL_Renderer *renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);
    SDL_Texture *texture = SDL_CreateTexture(renderer, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_ARGB8888, SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STATIC, windowWidth, windowHeight);

    Uint32 *pixels = NULL;
    pixels = (Uint32 *) malloc (sizeof(Uint32)*(Uint32)windowWidth*(Uint32)windowHeight);
    memset(pixels, 255, (Uint32)windowWidth*(Uint32)windowHeight*sizeof(Uint32));

    Uint32 finColour = 0x99FFCC;

    SDL_Point mouse_position;
    int success = 1;
    while(success)
    {
        SDL_Event userAction;

        SDL_GetMouseState(&mouse_position.x, &mouse_position.y);

        SDL_UpdateTexture(texture, NULL, pixels, (int)((Uint32)windowWidth * sizeof(Uint32)));

        while(SDL_PollEvent(&userAction))
        {
            switch(userAction.type)
            {
                case SDL_QUIT: success = 0; break;
                case SDL_KEYDOWN:
                    if(userAction.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_f)
                    {
                        myFill(pixels, windowWidth, windowHeight, 1, 1, finColour, &counter);
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }

        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
        SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, NULL, NULL);
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    }
    free(pixels);
    SDL_DestroyTexture(texture);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could be visiting a particular pixel twice. So by 20,000 times the entire portion is actually colored. But it takes 337,9977 iterations in total (because of some wrongly inserted calls).

Comment: You should probably move the check of `mySameColor` __before__ you increment the counter. Because you are wrongly incrementing the counter even when you are not actually doing anything in the function.

Comment: @Ajay Moving `mySameColour` does lower the total counts, but entering the `myFill` function to check colour still adds another level of depth to the recursion right? And if reaching the recursion limit is causing the segfault, then that's what I want to avoid.

Comment: but if that condition fails, it immediately returns. So it is okay. Say you colored pixel 1,1 . Then you called for 1,2. Now 1,2 will call 1,1 again. But it does nothing. Even then the counter is incremented. If you are worried about that extra function call, you can make this check __before__ you call the function. ie before each recursive call to `myFill`, do the check for `mySameColor`.

Comment: Also, if you truly want to measure the "depth", you should decrement the counter while leaving a function (I assume you know how the stack works). In that case too, you will see how it gets incremented and then immediately gets decremented because of the return.

Comment: @Ajay That sounds like a good idea and I would like to try that, but the linux terminal only shows the last 10,000 or so printf statements so I might not catch the deepest stack level reached? Know a simple way to save the highest number printed?

Comment: `if (*highest < *counter) {*highest = *counter; printf("new highest is %d", *highest);}` and pass along `int *highest` just like your pass `counter`.

Comment: @Ajay Great, thank you. I'm still left with this issue of not having a constant value for how many loops I need/how deep to go though because I'm still trying numerous different changes and getting sometimes the window fills fine and sometimes it doesn't fill but still segfaults.

Comment: You need to keep on going till 1) either your window is colored (this would happen automatically, you don't need to write any terminating condition. Eventually all your calls to myFill will return and your window will be colored) 2) You hit a predecided maximum depth. Now, if your question is how to decide a good number, that depends on your platform specific factors like how much stack does your OS give you. How much space does each of your stack frame take, how big images will you usually encounter. There is no one answer for this.

Comment: Having said that, using this safe limit on the stack is probably not the right approach for flood fill. Like you said, the correct approach for it would be to use a iterative algorithm. It is not that difficult. You can read about Depth First Search(DFS) or Breadth First Search(BFS). That usually works for flood fill.

Comment: @Ajay When I read about those techniques I find them too conceptual and I can't imagine how to translate that into a modification of my existing code so that's what I mean about it being out of my skill level.

Comment: I see, if that is the case, you can impose some superficial limit by experimenting several times how much does your system allow. Do mind though, that changing the code might change this number. Even compiling with different optimizations will also change this number. Moving to a different system will most definitely change this number. So, you will have to recaliberate it every time.

Comment: @Ajay I appreciate you discussing this with me. This program will only be used on my computer so I don't need to worry about making it adaptable. I will certainly keep that in mind when writing code for multiple systems though.